# Can't remove mode created by xrandr

Tags: xrandr

I have an additional mode that I would like to remove.

However, I cannot figure out how to remove the mode.

I'm running:

```
xrandr -q
```

which gives me:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 4480 x 1674, maximum 32767 x 32767
DVI-D-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00    59.94    50.00    23.98  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+594 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 520mm x 300mm
   1920x1080    144.00 + 144.00   119.93*   60.00  
   1680x1050    119.99    59.95  
   1440x900     119.85    59.89  
   1280x1024    119.96    75.02    60.02  
   1024x768     119.99    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I am interested in removing one of the 144.00 under `DP-0 1920x1080`.

running:

```
xrandr --delmode DP-0 1920x1080_144.00
```

gives me:

```
xrandr: cannot find mode "1920x1080_144.00"
```

I also tried removing a different mode (in case the issue had to do with having 2x 144.00)

```
xrandr --delmode DP-0 1680x1050_119.99
xrandr: cannot find mode "1680x1050_119.99"
```

If there was a way to list the names of modes that would likely help, but I haven't been able to find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed a mode that I created via the following:

```
xrandr --delmode HDMI-1 1440x1080
```

I gave it the resolution listed in the first column from `xandr -q`.

However, before that I created a new mode with `xrandr --newmode 1440x1080_60.00...` per online instructions, which put `1440x1080_60.00` in the first column. This was ugly so I deleted it with:

```
xrandr --delmode HDMI-1 1440x1080_60.00
```